# Connecting to SQLServer with Firedac in Delphi 10 Seattle

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using a grid to enter data and find that my fields that are marked as NOT NULL but have a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT eg. int = 0 are not being automatically updated with the default value.

Comment: Thanks for replying but have received an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Delphi XE8 documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Specifying_Default_Values_(FireDAC)):

> FireDAC does not automatically fetch column default expressions from
>   the database dictionary.

The standard Delphi way to define default values is to handle the **TDataSet.OnNewRecord** event and explicitly set the defaults at runtime.

But FireDAC does offer another solution:

> FireDAC allows you to assign an expression to the
>   **TField.DefaultExpression** property. This expression will be evaluated
>   one time as part of the Insert / Append method call and assigned as an
>   initial value to the corresponding field.

This can be done at design time using the fields editor.

I prefer the former solution, but that is because often my datasets are defined at runtime via dynamic SQL... so the latter is not an option.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and very helpful answer.